# Updating certain Primefaces Diagram Element

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am trying since 2 days to solve a issue I got with my primefaces diagram implementation.
I want on "mouseover" the diagram elements, highlight other elements that are connected with that element.
I have it working, but ONLY if I update the whole diagram/form when I update the elements.
I have two problems with that approach. 
First with the constant updates on mouseover all the binding on mouseenter and other stuff, gets reset so I have the event fire all the time although I just entered. Also 80% of the time I dont catch the mouseleave / hover leave event because of the constant calls.
Also I cant scroll the diagram anymore as the constant updates on mouseover would reset the scroll. ;-)

So I tried to only update the diagram elements I actually changed on mouseover, but I could not find a way that worked for me...

I tried just updateing the element via primefaces RequestContect.update
I used all variations on the Id like:
1-0201
diagram-1-0201
diagram:diagram-1-0201

I tried a javascript query from primefaces execute. I got a ui cant be resolved error on that one. Although the same query works on the xhtml. I also couldnt figure out that error. Although I dont think it would help, as the same code doesnt work when executed in the html file aswell.

I tried just saving the connections in a diagram element value and then accessing this value via hidden input on the elements. I got the ids for the connected elements in my javascript but I could not update the elements via javascript aswell. "inside" (leftover commented code) was the variable I had for the hidden inputs that were referenced on the Element variable that stored the connections)
I got both the list and the single connected ids in javascript but couldnt manage to update the elements.

I am not that experienced in javascript. I used it for the first time a few days ago.

So how do I update the style of certain elements in the primefaces diagram without reloading the hole diagram?
There must be a very easy way to do it or an easy way to fix my approaches I just cant see.
It is working if I update the whole diagram as I said, but I cant do that on mouseover for obvious reasons.

I am using primefaces 6.0 with a apache tomcat 8.5

Picture of the setup with ids: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFc1G.png

Picture of the javascript log for the events: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxlcy.jpg

my xhtml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="borderless">
        <h:graphicImage name="images/logo.gif" />
        <h:outputLabel styleClass="h1" value="Diagram Viewer" />
    </p:panelGrid>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewAction action="#{dataManager.onLoad}" />
    </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="tabMenuForm">
        <p:menubar styleClass=".ui-menu .ui-menuitem-link"
            model="#{dataManager.menuModel}" />
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="diagramForm">
        <p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false"
            closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images/defaultLoader.gif']}" />
        </p:dialog>
        <p:tooltip />
        <p:diagram id="diagram" value="#{dataManager.model}"
            styleClass="borderless" style="#{dataManager.diagramStyle}" var="el">
            <f:facet name="element" id="diagramElement" widgetVar="element">
                <h:outputLabel>
                    <p:commandLink
                        actionListener="#{tooltipManager.onElementClickedTwo()}"
                        styleClass="commandRemover">
                        <f:param name="selected" value="#{el.id}" />
                        <div class="elID">
                            <h:outputText value="#{el.id}" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="elName">
                            <h:outputText value="#{el.name}" sytleCLass="elName" />

                        </div>
                    </p:commandLink>
                </h:outputLabel>
                <!--  <h:outputText value="#{el.role}" style="display: inline; align-items: right; margin-top:0em;"/> -->

            </f:facet>
        </p:diagram>
        <p:remoteCommand name="elementMouseOver"
            actionListener="#{dataManager.onElementMouseOver}" />
        <p:remoteCommand name="elementMouseOut"
            actionListener="#{dataManager.onElementMouseOut}" />
        <h:inputHidden id="someId" value="#{dataManager.selectedId}" />
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $('.ui-diagram-element').hover(function(ev) {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(ev);
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                //var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                //console.log('INSIDE!' + inputs);
                //var input = inputs[0].val();
                //var val = $(input).val();
                //console.log('VAL: ' + val);
                //console.log('INSIDE!' + input);
                //var string = '#diagramForm\\:diagram-' + input;
                //$(string).addClass('ui-diagram-element-predecessor');
                //+ val[i]));
                elementMouseOver([ {
                    name : 'elementId',
                    value : id
                } ]);
                //console.log(val);
            }, function(ev) {
                //***leave***//
                var id = $(this).attr('id');

            });
        </script>
```

Important part of the Bean:

```
private DiagramNode selected;
    private String selectedId = "x";
    private List<String> selectedList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getSelectedId() {
        return selectedId;
    }

    public void setSelectedId(String selectedId) {
        this.selectedId = selectedId;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedList() {
        return selectedList;
    }

    public void setSelectedList(ArrayList<String> selectedList) {
        this.selectedList = selectedList;
    }

    public void onElementMouseOver() {
        String input = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("elementId");
        System.out.println("DataManager: Input: " + input);
        String[] mouseoverIdSplit = input.split("-", 2);
        if (mouseoverIdSplit.length < 2)
            return;

        System.out.println("DataManager: Mouseover:" + mouseoverIdSplit[1]);

        selected = DataLoader.WPCPTaskRows.get(mouseoverIdSplit[1]);
        selectedId = mouseoverIdSplit[1];
        selectedList = selected.connections;
        for (String id : selected.connections) {

            System.out.println("Setting StyleClass for " + id);
            String elementToUpdate = "diagramForm:diagram-" + id;
            System.out.println(elementToUpdate);
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(elementToUpdate);


            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance()
                    .execute("$('#" + elementToUpdate + "').addClass(ui-diagram-element-predecessor);");
        }

        // RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("scriptBean");
        // RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("someId");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("diagramForm");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("diagram");

    }

public class DiagramElement implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private String name;
        private String id;
        private String role;
        private String predecessor;
        private List<String> predecessorList;

        public DiagramElement() {
        }

        public DiagramElement(String name, String id, String role, String predecessor, List<String> predecessorList) {
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
            this.role = role;
            this.predecessor = predecessor;
            this.predecessorList = predecessorList;
        }

+getter and setter
```

Answer (score 0):

After more then 10 hours of insanity I FINALLY got it working.
I connected the strings for the ID in javascript not correctly.
Also I had to add 3 \\ to the string, because 1 was swallowed as a escape and I needed 2 for a javascript function to find the element with a ":" inside it.

Here is how I did it in the end:

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{el.predecessorList}" />
$('.ui-diagram-element').hover(
                        function(ev) {
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            console.log(ev);
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                            console.log(inputs);
                            var input = inputs[1];
                            //var val = $(input).val();
                            //console.log('VAL: ' + val);
                            var array = input.value;
                            console.log(array);
                            var parsedArray = array.replace("[", "").replace("]",
                                    "").replace(/\s/g, "").split(',');
                            for ( var pos in parsedArray) {
                                var str1 = '#diagramForm\\\:diagram-';
                                var str2 = parsedArray[pos];
                                console.log(str2);
                                var con = str1.concat(str2);
                                console.log(con);
                                $(con).addClass('ui-diagram-element-predecessor');
                            }
                        },
                        function(ev) {
                            //***leave***//
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            console.log(ev);
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var inputs = $(this).find('input');
                            console.log(inputs);
                            var input = inputs[1];
                            //var val = $(input).val();
                            //console.log('VAL: ' + val);
                            var array = input.value;
                            console.log(array);
                            var parsedArray = array.replace("[", "").replace("]",
                                    "").replace(/\s/g, "").split(',');
                            for ( var pos in parsedArray) {
                                var str1 = '#diagramForm\\\:diagram-';
                                var str2 = parsedArray[pos];
                                console.log(str2);
                                var con = str1.concat(str2);
                                console.log(con);
                                $(con).removeClass('ui-diagram-element-predecessor');
                            }
    });
```